# Rundeck Job fails cause verbose output

Tags: powershell, rundeck

I´m currently running in the issue that my Rundeck Job fails cause it write a verbose message. Is there any possibility to change this behavior from rundeck?

My Job is a basic power shell command:
`Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder" -Recurse -File | Where CreationTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)  | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose`

Without the -verbose I don´t see which file was deleted, but I´d like to see this.

Someone any idea?

Comment: Seems strange that it would fail with the `-verbose` switch. I've never used Rundeck but do you [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102017/how-to-run-a-powershell-command-in-rundeck-with-pipes) your PowerShell script correctly?

Comment: Yes I use Rundeck also on Windows which uses powershell to execute $things